# CSV parsing & testing with Python and Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to test, in Python,  a series of some output CSV files, where on each CSV I am trying to read and and parse it so that I want to test for the following things in it. (currently testing with Pycharm ide and also windows CLI)

1. Assert if that csv file is present
2. Assert that x number of columns are present in the csv header
3. Assert that certain column heads are present (ex: TITLE, DOB & MAN_ID)
4. Then generate an Html report with results

Here is the sample, test csv file that i am using.

```
MAN_ID,TITLE,YOB,MOB,DOB,BDT,DT,RC_ID,EC_ID,L_ID,PID,CS_ID,PSV,GSV,GSC_ID,RSV,RSC_ID,ESV,ESC_ID
1,,1946,5,2,00:00:00.019460,,,,,0,,,F,,,,,
9,,1981,2,21,00:00:00.019810,,,,,9,,,M,,,,,
8,,1957,12,12,00:00:00.019571,,,,,8,,,M,,,,,
7,,1990,3,19,00:00:00.019900,,,,,7,,,F,,,,,
6,,1976,8,18,00:00:00.019760,,,,,6,,,F,,,,,
5,,1976,11,10,00:00:00.019761,,,,,5,,,M,,,,,
4,,1981,7,19,00:00:00.019810,,,,,4,,,M,,,,,
3,,1989,1,8,00:00:00.019890,,,,,4,,,M,,,,,
2,,1985,3,28,00:00:00.019850,,,,,4,,,M,,,,,
```

Here is what i have tried so far,

1. Could assert that file is present or not
2. Trying to convert my csv into a pandas dataframe (not able to do it properly currently)
3. Then Use that pandas dataframe to assertions on Columns, Column names, null values etc (currently failing here as step 2 fails)

My current Python test script code

```
import csv
import os.path
from os import path
import pandas as pd
import pytest

assert path.exists("C:\Work\Tests\test.csv"), "test.csv file does not exists"
p = "C:\Work\Tests\test.csv"
path.exists(p)

file = open(p, newline='')

reader = csv.reader(file)

header = next(reader) # The first line ie Header/title is Skipped in the CSV file
data = [row for row in reader] # Read the remaining data

#Checking for presence of test.csv
def main():
    print ("File exists:"+str(path.exists(p)))

if __name__== "__main__":
   main()

#defining Print all
def printAll():
    print(header) # print just the header columns
    print(data[1]) # printing second row
    #print(data) # printing all csv data
    #print(pd.read_csv(p)) ##printing csv data in table as rows and columns
    print('Success')

printAll()

"""
df = pd.DataFrame({pd.read_csv(p)}, columns=['TITLE', 'DOB', 'MAN_ID'])
#print("Printing Dataframe: "+df)
print("dataframe not head.....")
#print(pd.read_csv(p).head())
#print(pd.read_csv(p))
#print(df.shape)
#print(len(df.index))
#print(len(df.columns))

print(len(pd.read_csv(p)))
```

Kindly suggest me 
1. how can get the pandas dataframe from csv file and then do my needed assertions and reporting.
2. Can I achieve all this with Pytest as well ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I my answer below was satisfactory could you kindly accept the answer as correct? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Run-out, Yes I am about to, but do you know if I Can I achieve all this above tests with Pytest as well ?

Comment: Have you tried it with the documentation at [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org)? You need to create a test file with test assert statements on functions. You can import your main program into the test file, and then make asserts to validate information like in my answer below. Then you can run the test file from the terminal and it will tell you if the assert statements passed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pd.read_csv('filename')

```
import Pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('parsing.csv')
print(df)

   MAN_ID  TITLE   YOB  MOB  DOB              BDT  DT  RC_ID  EC_ID  L_ID  \
0       1    NaN  1946    5    2  00:00:00.019460 NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   
1       9    NaN  1981    2   21  00:00:00.019810 NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   
2       8    NaN  1957   12   12  00:00:00.019571 NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   
3       7    NaN  1990    3   19  00:00:00.019900 NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   
4       6    NaN  1976    8   18  00:00:00.019760 NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   
5       5    NaN  1976   11   10  00:00:00.019761 NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   
6       4    NaN  1981    7   19  00:00:00.019810 NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   
7       3    NaN  1989    1    8  00:00:00.019890 NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   
8       2    NaN  1985    3   28  00:00:00.019850 NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
```

more columns:

```
   PID  CS_ID  PSV GSV  GSC_ID  RSV  RSC_ID  ESV  ESC_ID  
0    0    NaN  NaN   F     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  
1    9    NaN  NaN   M     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  
2    8    NaN  NaN   M     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  
3    7    NaN  NaN   F     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  
4    6    NaN  NaN   F     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  
5    5    NaN  NaN   M     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  
6    4    NaN  NaN   M     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  
7    4    NaN  NaN   M     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  
8    4    NaN  NaN   M     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN
```

Total columns:

```
df.shape[1]

19
```

Column names:

```
df.columns

Index(['MAN_ID', 'TITLE', 'YOB', 'MOB', 'DOB', 'BDT', 'DT', 'RC_ID', 'EC_ID',
       'L_ID', 'PID', 'CS_ID', 'PSV', 'GSV', 'GSC_ID', 'RSV', 'RSC_ID', 'ESV',
       'ESC_ID'],
      dtype='object')
```

Specific column name in columns:

```
'YOB' in df.columns

True
```

Check for null values.

```
df.isna()

  MAN_ID  TITLE    YOB    MOB    DOB    BDT    DT  RC_ID  EC_ID  L_ID    PID  \
0   False   True  False  False  False  False  True   True   True  True  False   
1   False   True  False  False  False  False  True   True   True  True  False   
2   False   True  False  False  False  False  True   True   True  True  False   
3   False   True  False  False  False  False  True   True   True  True  False   
4   False   True  False  False  False  False  True   True   True  True  False   
5   False   True  False  False  False  False  True   True   True  True  False   
6   False   True  False  False  False  False  True   True   True  True  False   
7   False   True  False  False  False  False  True   True   True  True  False   
8   False   True  False  False  False  False  True   True   True  True  False
```

More columns:

```
  CS_ID   PSV    GSV  GSC_ID   RSV  RSC_ID   ESV  ESC_ID  
0   True  True  False    True  True    True  True    True  
1   True  True  False    True  True    True  True    True  
2   True  True  False    True  True    True  True    True  
3   True  True  False    True  True    True  True    True  
4   True  True  False    True  True    True  True    True  
5   True  True  False    True  True    True  True    True  
6   True  True  False    True  True    True  True    True  
7   True  True  False    True  True    True  True    True  
8   True  True  False    True  True    True  True    True
```